# Linking multiple incompatible versions of a static library into one executable

Tags: c, static-libraries

I am presently developing for a system which discourages (i.e. essentially forbids) dynamic libraries. Therefore, everything has to be linked statically.

The application framework I am using (which cannot be changed) is using an old, statically-linked version of a library `libfoo.a` (version r7). A library I am using, `libbar`, needs `libfoo.a` version r8 (specifically, some of the new features are crucial for the library to function). I can edit and recompile `libbar` as well as `libfoo` r8, but I want to avoid changing them as much as possible because I am not very familiar with the code (and would have to pass code changes upstream).

Unfortunately, the two `libfoo` libraries have a substantial number of symbols in common. So, the linker spits out a ton of "multiple symbol definition" errors.

I've heard it's possible to use `objcopy` and friends to "inline" a static library into another. However, I'm not really sure how to achieve this in practice, nor if it's even the best option.

So, how can I successfully compile an executable which uses two, incompatible versions of the same library? I've already considered avoiding this situation but it will be much harder to work with.

Comment: Hm, `objcopy --localize-symbol` looks promising. Maybe you can first make an archive of the old library and the objects that need it, and then hide all the now-internal symbols?

Comment: I can confirm that I've used objcopy to rename symbols in libraries to deal with duplicate symbols used in different libraries, e.g. libx and liby both link with libz, now I want to link in both libx and liby, so libz symbols appear twice. I solved it by renaming the libc symbols in each so that they each happily call their own version with their own symbol name prefix. I can't find the script yet but if I do I will let you know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that this is actually possible with some `ld` and `objcopy` magic.

Basically, the procedure looks like this:

```
# Unpack libraries
ar x libbar.a
ar x libfoo.a
# Grab symbol table (symbols to export)
nm -Ag libbar.a | grep -v ' U ' | cut -d' ' -f 3 > libbar.sym
# Build a single object file with libfoo relocated in
ld -Er *.o -o libbar-merged.lo
# Localize all symbols except for libbar's symbols
objcopy --keep-global-symbols libbar.sym libbar-merged.lo libbar-merged.o
# Create an archive to hold the merged library
ar crs libbar-merged.a libbar-merged.o
```

This effectively creates a single super-library which exports only the symbols from the original `libbar`, and which has the other library relocated in.

There's probably another, cleaner way to achieve this result, but this method works for me and allows me to statically link two incompatible libraries into the same executable, with no apparent ill effects.

Comment: By the way, the `nm` command is kind of nasty. So, if there's a nicer way to get a list of all defined, global symbols in a library, I'm all ears.